# Python fast static file serving

Tags: python

What's the fastest way to serve static files in Python? I'm looking for something equal or close enough to Nginx's static file serving.

I know of SimpleHTTPServer but not sure if it can handle serving multiple files efficiently and reliably.

Also, I don't mind it being a part of a lib/framework of some sort as long as its lib/framework is lightweight.

Comment: This really isn't a job for Python. What's wrong with Nginx?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: I can imagine Ngix is less practical to package and deploy with a Python application.

Comment: @DanielRoseman because I need something Python based and lightweight as possible yet efficient. I'm writing a small package and I want the static file serving bundled there instead of relying on external dependencies like Nginx.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT: This project appears to be dead.**

---

What about [FAPWS3](https://github.com/william-os4y/fapws3)? One of the selling points:

> **Static file server**
>
> FAPWS can be used to serve a huge amount of static file requests. With the help of a async database in the backend, you can use FAPWS as your own Amazon S3.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen this one and might actually consider it. Just need more inputs that's why I asked.

Comment: The link seems to lead to an extremely shady page filled with questionable Chinese advertisements. Perhaps it's long dead?

Comment: @natiiix Yep, thanks. I updated the link to point to the Github repo instead.

Answer (score 2):

Original [SimpleHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/simplehttpserver.html) from python standard library does NOT "*handle serving multiple files efficiently and reliably*". For instance, if you are downloading one file from it, another HTTP access to it must be hovering since `SimpleHTTPServer.py` is **a simple singal-thread HTTP server** which could **only support one connecting simultaneously**.

Fortunately, note that `SimpleHTTPServer.py` use [BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/basehttpserver.html#BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer) as handler, which can be wrapped by [SocketServer.ForkingMixIn](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/socketserver.html#SocketServer.ForkingMixIn) and [SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/socketserver.html#SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn) also from python standard library to support multi-process and multi-thread mode, which could highly enhance simple HTTP server's "*efficience and reliability*".

According to this idea, a **SimpleHTTPServer with multi-thread/multi-process support** modified from original one is given as follows:

```
$ python2.7 ModifiedSimpleHTTPServer.py
usage: ModifiedSimpleHTTPServer.py [-h] [--pydoc] [--port PORT]
                                   [--type {process,thread}] [--root ROOT]
                                   [--run]

Modified SimpleHTTPServer with MultiThread/MultiProcess and IP bind support.

Original:    https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/simplehttpserver.html
Modified by: vbem@163.com

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --pydoc               show this module's pydoc

run arguments:

  --port PORT           specify server port (default: 8000)
  --type {process,thread}
                        specify server type (default: 'thread')
  --root ROOT           specify root directory (default: cwd '/home/vbem')
  --run                 run http server foreground

NOTE: stdin for input, stdout for result, stderr for logging
```

For example, `ModifiedSimpleHTTPServer.py --run --root /var/log --type process` will run a multi-process HTTP static files server with '/var/log' as its root directory.

Modified codes are:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
r"""Modified SimpleHTTPServer with MultiThread/MultiProcess and IP bind support.

Original:    https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/simplehttpserver.html
Modified by: vbem@163.com
"""

# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
import os, sys, pwd, posixpath, BaseHTTPServer, urllib, cgi, shutil, mimetypes, socket, SocketServer, BaseHTTPServer
from cStringIO import StringIO

USERNAME = pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid()).pw_name
HOSTNAME = socket.gethostname()
PORT_DFT = 8000

class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    server_version = "SimpleHTTP/0.6"

    def do_GET(self):
        f = self.send_head()
        if f:
            self.copyfile(f, self.wfile)
            f.close()

    def do_HEAD(self):
        f = self.send_head()
        if f:
            f.close()

    def send_head(self):
        path = self.translate_path(self.path)
        f = None
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            if not self.path.endswith('/'):
                self.send_response(301)
                self.send_header("Location", self.path + "/")
                self.end_headers()
                return None
            for index in "index.html", "index.htm":
                index = os.path.join(path, index)
                if os.path.exists(index):
                    path = index
                    break
            else:
                return self.list_directory(path)
        ctype = self.guess_type(path)
        try:
            f = open(path, 'rb')
        except IOError:
            self.send_error(404, "File not found")
            return None
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", ctype)
        fs = os.fstat(f.fileno())
        self.send_header("Content-Length", str(fs[6]))
        self.send_header("Last-Modified", self.date_time_string(fs.st_mtime))
        self.end_headers()
        return f

    def list_directory(self, path):
        try:
            list = ['..'] + os.listdir(path) # 
        except os.error:
            self.send_error(404, "No permission to list directory")
            return None
        list.sort(key=lambda a: a.lower())
        f = StringIO()
        displaypath = cgi.escape(urllib.unquote(self.path))
        f.write('<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">')
        f.write("<html>\n<title>%s %s</title>\n<body>" % (HOSTNAME, displaypath))
        f.write("%s@%s:<strong>%s</strong>\n" % (USERNAME, HOSTNAME, path.rstrip('/')+'/'))
        f.write("<hr>\n<ul>\n")
        for name in list:
            fullname = os.path.join(path, name)
            displayname = linkname = name
            if os.path.isdir(fullname):
                displayname = name + "/"
                linkname = name + "/"
            if os.path.islink(fullname):
                displayname = name + "@"
            f.write('<li><a href="%s">%s</a>\n'
                    % (urllib.quote(linkname), cgi.escape(displayname)))
        f.write("</ul>\n<hr>\n<pre>%s</pre>\n</body>\n</html>\n" % __doc__)
        length = f.tell()
        f.seek(0)
        self.send_response(200)
        encoding = sys.getfilesystemencoding()
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html; charset=%s" % encoding)
        self.send_header("Content-Length", str(length))
        self.end_headers()
        return f

    def translate_path(self, path):
        path = path.split('?',1)[0]
        path = path.split('#',1)[0]
        path = posixpath.normpath(urllib.unquote(path))
        words = path.split('/')
        words = filter(None, words)
        path = os.getcwd()
        for word in words:
            drive, word = os.path.splitdrive(word)
            head, word = os.path.split(word)
            if word in (os.curdir, os.pardir): continue
            path = os.path.join(path, word)
        return path

    def copyfile(self, source, outputfile):
        shutil.copyfileobj(source, outputfile)

    def guess_type(self, path):
        base, ext = posixpath.splitext(path)
        if ext in self.extensions_map:
            return self.extensions_map[ext]
        ext = ext.lower()
        if ext in self.extensions_map:
            return self.extensions_map[ext]
        else:
            return self.extensions_map['']

    if not mimetypes.inited:
        mimetypes.init()
    extensions_map = mimetypes.types_map.copy()
    extensions_map.update({'': 'text/plain'})

class ProcessedHTTPServer(SocketServer.ForkingMixIn, BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer):
    r"""Handle requests in multi process."""

class ThreadedHTTPServer(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn, BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer):
    r"""Handle requests in a separate thread."""

SERVER_DICT = {
    'thread'    : ThreadedHTTPServer,
    'process'   : ProcessedHTTPServer,
}
SERVER_DFT = 'thread'

def run(sCwd=None, sServer=SERVER_DFT, nPort=PORT_DFT, *lArgs, **dArgs):
    r"""
    """
    sys.stderr.write('start with %r\n' % sys._getframe().f_locals)
    if sCwd is not None:
        os.chdir(sCwd)
    cServer = SERVER_DICT[sServer]
    oHttpd = cServer(("", nPort), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
    sys.stderr.write('http://%s:%s/\n' % (HOSTNAME, nPort))
    oHttpd.serve_forever()

# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
# main

def _main():
    r"""Main.
    """
    import argparse

    oParser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description = __doc__,
        formatter_class = argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter,
        epilog = 'NOTE: stdin for input, stdout for result, stderr for logging',
    )
    oParser.add_argument('--pydoc', action='store_true',
        help = "show this module's pydoc",
    )

    oGroupR = oParser.add_argument_group(title='run arguments', description='')
    oGroupR.add_argument('--port', action='store', type=int, default=PORT_DFT,
        help = 'specify server port (default: %(default)r)',
    )
    oGroupR.add_argument('--type', action='store', default=SERVER_DFT, choices=SERVER_DICT.keys(),
        help = 'specify server type (default: %(default)r)',
    )
    oGroupR.add_argument('--root', action='store', default=os.getcwd(),
        help = 'specify root directory (default: cwd %(default)r)',
    )
    oGroupR.add_argument('--run', action='store_true',
        help = '\n'.join((
            'run http server foreground',
    )))

    oArgs = oParser.parse_args()

    if oArgs.pydoc:
        help(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(__file__))[0])
    elif oArgs.run:
        return run(sCwd=oArgs.root, sServer=oArgs.type, nPort=oArgs.port)
    else:
        oParser.print_help()
        return 1

    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    exit(_main())
```

Meanwhile, the single python file with only 200 lines may satisfy your "*in Python*" and "*lightweight*" demands.

Last but not least, this `ModifiedSimpleHTTPServer.py` may be a "killer app" by hand for temporary use, however, Nginx is advised for long term use.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend using a 3rd party HTTP server to serve static files.

Servers like nginx are heavily optimized for the task at hand, parallelized and written in fast languages.

Python is tied to one processor and interpreted.

Comment: > interpreted.
Dosen't matter much , File serving is IOBound.

Comment: `Python is tied to one processor`
It is not , it was never tied to One processor. Only GIL lock at Threading . Python mutliprocessing standard library and many parallel processing 3rd party libraries are better than threading and they all work on multi processor.

Answer (score 1):

If you look for a oneliner you can do the following:

> $> python -m SimpleHTTPServer

This will not fullfil all the task required but worth mentioning that this *is* the simplest way :-)

Comment: I know of SimpleHTTPServer, I mentioned it above. :)